# Hibernate One-To-Many Match multiple Ids

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I am using Hibernate 4 and JSF 2.

Given the following mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "feature")
public class Feature 
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_feature", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "feature_id"))
    private Set<Feature> features = new HashSet<Feature>(0);

}
```

Database Structure

```
Product
---------
id
name

Feature
---------
id
name

Product_Feature
----------------
product_id
feature_id
```

What I want to do now, is build a DetachedCriteria to get all products that have, let's say the features 1,2 and 3. Not only one of them, but all of them.

I just cannot get the restriction right, to find the products to match ALL given features, not only one.

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.for(Product.class, "product");
criteria.createAlias("product.features", "feature");
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its possible using `Restrictions`:  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3227273/1029758

Comment: As stated below, this only ensures, that the product has one of the defined features, but does not ensure that it has ALL defined features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following sql restriction.

```
String features = "1,4,5";
int featureSize = 3;

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.for(Product.class, "product");

criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(String.format("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_feature pf where pf.feature_id in(%s) and pf.product_id={alias}.id)=%d", features, featureSize)));
```

This ensures, that the product has ALL three features, not only one or two.